# Joining Tables in Laravel 4.2 Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm not so good at making queries using Laravel Eloquent. I've two tables

```
stories table
------------------------------------------------------------------
 id |   title   |   body   | author_id |...
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | Story 1   | Once a.. |  2
 2  | Story 2   | There is |  4
 3  | Something | You are. |  2

 activities table
------------------------------------------------------------------
 id | story_id | liker_id |...
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 2        | 2
```

Here `author_id` & `liker_id` are actually `user_id`. I want to get the **Stories** authored and liked by a specific **user** to display these stories in his profile.

I want to use the Eloquent ORM. I tried something like this using query builder

```
 $stories = DB::table('stories')
                ->join('activities', function($join)
                {
                  $join->on('stories.author_id', '=', 'activities.liker_id')
                })
                ->where('stories.author_id', $author_id)
                ->get();
 return $stories;
```

I can get `story_id` for a specific `liker_id` by `join` but couldn't get the details from `stories` table using `story_id` in a **Single** query.

Comment: Maybe you could create a model for each table and could do something like this $all = Activities::with('stories')->get()

Comment: @lajosArpad How can I implement `where` `author_id` for `stories` and `liker_id` in `Activities::with('stories')->get()`?

Comment: I am not a laravel user, but I have been working with ORMs for years. You should have a possibility to define the join paths. For instance you might have a joining table activity_stories having foreign keys to activities and stories. If that is the case, you can load activity_stories with activities and stories.

Comment: Looks like you need [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

Comment: @lajosArpad You mean I need another table that contains both `stories` & `activities` data and then make a query to that table, right?

Comment: More exactly I mean you might want to have a join table, which has only an id, a stories_id and an activities_id. stories_id being foreign key to stories and activities_id being foreign key to activities. This join table might be the missing part of the join chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple method with query builder to get Stories authored and liked by a specific user

```
$author_id = 1;
$stories = DB::table('stories')
            ->join('activities', 'stories.author_id', '=', DB::raw('activities.liker_id AND stories.id = activities.story_id'))
            ->Where('stories.author_id', $author_id)
            ->get();
//select * from `stories` inner join `activities` on `stories`.`author_id` = activities.liker_id AND stories.id = activities.story_id where `stories`.`author_id` = 1"
```

> with Eloquent you can do as following create 2 model file
>   1. Story model (Story.php)
>   2. Activity Model (Activity.php)
>   Story.php

```
class Story extends Eloquent {

    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Activity');
    }

}
```

Activity.php

```
class Activity extends Eloquent {

    public function story()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Story');
    }

}
```

than you can write function within Story to get data as your need

```
$stories = Story::with('activities')
                    ->where(DB::raw('stories.id = activities.story_id'))
                    ->Where('stories.author_id', $author_id)
                    ->get();
// haven't tested with eloquent but it should work
```